# How to import LAS to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import

I need to import LAS files to QGIS. I've never worked with GIS till now. Could anybody explain me this problem to the details? I've installed Quantum GIS v. 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, AFAIK. There was a discussion on the [gdal-dev](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-LAS-format-driver-for-OGR-td3745337.html) mailist a year ago about this question.

You probably want to have a look at the [las2ogr](http://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2ogr.html) tool to get your point cloud into a format usable by QGIS.

Also, be sure to check out how GRASS handles LAS point clouds.